# Getting this error on running terrafor apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "tf_storage_account_data_lake_gen2" {
  name                     = var.tfv_storage_account_data_lake_gen2_Name
  resource_group_name      = var.resourcegroup
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.tfv_storage_account_data_lake_gen2_account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.tfv_storage_account_data_lake_gen2_account_replication_type
  account_kind             = var.tfv_storage_account_data_lake_gen2_account_kind
  is_hns_enabled           = var.tfv_storage_account_data_lake_gen2_is_hns_enabled
  tags                      = var.tfv_tag
 
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  depends_on = [data.azurerm_client_config.current]
}


resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "raw" {
  name               = var.tfv_data_lake_gen2_raw_name
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.tf_storage_account_data_lake_gen2.id
}
```

---

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "tf_storage_account" {
  name                     = var.tfv_storage_account_name
  resource_group_name      = var.resourcegroup
  location                 = var.location
  account_tier             = var.tfv_account_tier
  account_replication_type = var.tfv_account_replication_type
  tags                = var.tfv_tag
  
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  depends_on = [data.azurerm_client_config.current]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "tf_storage_container" {
  name                  = var.tfv_container_Name
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.tf_storage_account.name
  container_access_type = var.tfv_access_type
  #depends_on            = [azurerm_storage_account.tf_storage_account]
  #azurerm_storage_account_customer_managed_key.tf_storage_account_customer_managed_key
}
```

---

Error: checking for existence of existing File System "stream1" (Account "azaotcsdlg2dev"): datalakestore.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: error response cannot be parsed: "" error: EOF

with module.DataLakeGen2.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.raw,
on ....\Modules\DataServices\DataLakeGen2\DataLakeGen2.tf line 29, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "raw":
29: resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "raw" {

Error: containers.Client#GetProperties: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailure" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation.\nRequestId:2b202b02-b01e-0051-07fa-d542e3000000\nTime:2021-11-10T06:16:44.7852698Z"

with module.StorageAccount.azurerm_storage_container.tf_storage_container,

Comment: Very hard to guess only withe the error stacktrace. It would be good to add some description of what you are doing and specially the code around the `DataLakeGen2.tf line 29`

Comment: The best that I can say is that you dont have permissions, hence the `AuthorizationFailure`

Comment: Hello @SandeepKumar, Please add the terraform script that you are using and more details .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Terraform - AzureDataLake Create Error Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382379/terraform-azuredatalake-create-error-failure-responding-to-request-statuscode)

Answer (score -3):

```
    data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
        }
        resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "example-resources"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
      name                = "virtnetname"
      address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
      name                 = "subnetname"
      resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
      address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
      service_endpoints    = ["Microsoft.Sql", "Microsoft.Storage"]
    }
        resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
          name                     = "abcdefg"
          resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
          location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
          account_tier             = "Premium"
          account_replication_type = "ZRS"
          account_kind             = "BlockBlobStorage"
          is_hns_enabled           = true
  network_rules {
    default_action             = "Deny"
    ip_rules                   = ["100.0.0.1"]
    virtual_network_subnet_ids = [azurerm_subnet.example.id]
  }
         
          identity {
            type = "SystemAssigned"
          }
        }
        
        
        resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "raw" {
          name               = "raw"
          storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.tf_storage_account_data_lake_gen2.id
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't look line an answer, there is only a code snippet. If you need to edit your question, please do. If you intend to provide a solution, please add a description.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).